# How do I /testfor more than 1 item in an inventory without a need to use the /scoreboard command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to test for more than 1 item in one's inventory. However, I'm having some difficulties.

I have tried the `/testfor @p[r=2] {Inventory [{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget"}]}` command, but it doesn't work. It says "UUID incorrect". I would rather not use scoreboards, because I don't really get along too well with it.

Can someone please put the command to set the amount? (I.E. Of the gold nuggets). If it matters, I would like it in command block form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem with not using scoreboards is you can test that there is a player that meets conditions with `/testfor` fine, but you can't *do* anything with that player. All you know is that player exists, but a different command block doesn't know who he is. In any case, I'll look into this in a bit.

Comment: There is no good reason not to use the scoreboard.  `scoreboard` is your friend.  `testfor` is not your friend, he's the guy that's really popular in your school, and pretends to be your friend, but that's just so he can get close to you in order to shove you in a locker, because that's all that he's good for.  Everyone thinks they should like `testfor` and that they should be around him, but he's just a shallow twerp that can barely do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple syntax errors in the NBT portion of your `/testfor` command. The command, as you have it, should be `/testfor @p[r=2] {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:gold_nugget}]}`

However, unless you literally only want to do something to the world whenever there is a player within 2 blocks with a gold nugget in their inventory, you are not going to be able to do anything with this `testfor` command. `testfor` does not allow you to pass player information to any other commands. You can see if that player exists, great, but you can't do anything to that player. If you want to do anything to that particular player, you will absolutely need to use a scoreboard. I don't care if you don't want to learn it, that's your only choice (if you just want to do something simple like summon a TNT at a particular location, then you can continue on your merry way with your `testfor` I guess).

Comment: You are missing part of the question. OP asked how he can test for a player with at least X gold nuggets, rather than any amount.

Comment: No, what i mean, like im making a bit of a start of a map, and the currencye is gold nuggets. For example, i have an enchanting room with some enchantments, with prices. Protection level 1 is 10 gold nuggets. I would like to make it, so that it takes the 10 gold nuggets from you and adds the enchantment. if you dont have 10 gold nuggets, it dosent enchant.

Comment: @MrLemon Right. At *least* is complicated. *Exactly* is less so. Hmm.......

Comment: @TOMDIEGO Hmm. I'll revisit this when I have access to Minecraft to come up with a more comprehensive solution. You can do *exactly* 10 nuggets, which will count if the player has a separate stack of 10 with `{Inventory:[{id:minecraft:gold_nugget,Count:10b}]}`, but I'll get a more comprehensive solution running later today

Comment: @TOMDIEGO if you want to build adventure maps, there are two sets of commands you absolutely need to know and be comfortable using, and they are `execute` and `scoreboard` commands.  Everything else is just specialized filler that either reacts to a scoreboard and/or is part of an execute.

Answer (score -1):

If you do these setup commands:

/scoreboard objectives add items dummy

/stats entity @a set AffectedItems @p items

/scoreboard players set @a items 0

Then run this command: (N.B. The execute is ESSENTIAL)

/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /clear @p minecraft:gold_ingot 0

This will then mean that each player has the number of gold ingots in their inventory as their items score.